# Properly process Svelte files with CoffeeScript/Pug in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, coffeescript, svelte

I modified the Svelte starter template so CoffeeScript can be used via svelte-preprocess. VS Code displays "problems" for Svelte files because the CoffeeScript is being interpreted as JavaScript:

[image]

Note this is only a problem with the VS Code tooling; when the project is built the CoffeeScript is correctly detected and compiled into JavaScript.

**Why is VS Code processing the CoffeeScript as JavaScript?** Steps I tried to configure VS Code for Svelte + CoffeeScript:

1. Install [Svelte for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=svelte.svelte-vscode) extension.
2. Add svelte.config.js file in project root, per [these instructions](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/blob/master/docs/preprocessors/in-general.md#using-preprocessors):

> If a svelte file contains some language other than html, css or
> javascript, svelte-vscode needs to know how to preprocess it. This can
> be achieved by creating a svelte.config.js file...

3. Restart the language server.

At first I tried the simple svelte.config.js from the instructions above. Then I modified it to ensure both [Svelte language tools and rollup use the exact same configuration](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/blob/master/docs/preprocessors/in-general.md#deduplicating-your-configs):

```
// svelte.config.js   
const sveltePreprocess = require('svelte-preprocess');

function createPreprocessors() {
  return sveltePreprocess({
    defaults: {
      markup: 'pug',
      script: 'coffeescript',
      style: 'css'
    },
    coffeescript: {
      bare: true
    }
  })
}

module.exports = {
  preprocess: createPreprocessors(),
  createPreprocessors
};
```

I have also confirmed VS Code correctly processes pure CoffeeScript files with .coffee extension.

The entire project is available at: [github.com/Leftium/svelte-coffeescript-pug](https://github.com/Leftium/svelte-coffeescript-pug)

Answer (score 0):

Do you also have this issue when using `<script lang="coffee">`?

Comment: Yes. The problem is the svelte language tools still process that section (and the template lang=pug section) as if the code were JS/TS. The work-around is to set this setting to false: `svelte.plugin.typescript.enable`.